# How can i open html page in fancybox and redirect this html to another html page in fancybox with fancybox resizing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox-2

> How can i open html page in fancybox and redirect this html to another html page in **fancybox** with fancybox re-sizing?

I have tried below code yet:

- Href is the another page link which i want to open in fancy box on click id **fancybox-manual-e**

Link:

```
<a id="fancybox-manual-e"  href="loginby.html" class="forgotPwd floatR">Forgot Password?</a>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#fancybox-manual-e").click(function() {
    $.fancybox.open({
        'href' : 'loginby.html',
        'type' : 'iframe',
        'padding' : 5,
        'width': 800,
        'height': 500,
    });

});
```

Comment: I am not totally sure I understand `redirect this html to another html page in fancybox with fancybox resizing?` ... could you elaborate on `with fancybox resizing`?